# AR Multiplayer: How to share the position of the 3D object, relative to the image target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit, multiplayer, arcore

I'm trying to implement a very basic ARCore-ARKit multiplayer in Unity. I can use markers to place 3D content over them using Vuforia or ARKit/ARCore image recognition.

But how can I store and share across several devices (iOS and Android) the position of the 3D object, relative to the image target?

I can't find any useful tutorial on this topic.

Comment: "Users in the same environment can add Cloud Anchors to the AR scene that they see on their device." https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/cloud-anchors/overview-unity

Answer (score 0):

You can make the 3D objects child objects of your image anchor and share the local position. For the sharing you can use [Unity networking](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking)